# Finding Failures Within Last 3 days of Orders Per Customer

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, time

I'm trying to write a query which is confusing me.

In essence, what I'm trying to look for is check the customer, look for the last 3 days where jobs were done and if each day has a failure, then it performs an action on that customer.

So customer A) Could have had jobs all week (I'll use this week as an example), 20/10 (Failure), 19/10 (Failure), 18/10 (Failure) would work
And Customer B) only has jobs fortnightly (20/10) (Failure), 05/10 (Failure), 20/09, (Failure)

What I am confused about, is I am not sure how to filter on the orders where I'm not looking at the orders themselves, but instead 3 seperate days where orders have been done

I was thinking of a top 3 dates, but the customer could have multiple jobs in a day and I need to find all of the orders for the last 3 days where jobs were done

```
SELECT distinct TOP 3 DATEPART(DAY,od.datetimeCreated), of.uniqueID  FROM order.
data od LEFT JOIN order.dataFailure of ON of.orderID = od.orderID
```

This gives me something similar to what I want, however I still want to see all of the data for those 3 days

Could anyone give me some pointers on how I could go about this?

Sample Data:

Not sure what data would help with this issue, in essence, when the orderID from order.data is inside order.dataFailure, then we consider it a failure, else if it joins as a null, it hasn't failed.

As for dates, I compare the dates on a field called datetimeCreated and datetimeFailed, and then group it by a customer account code

[image: Image of table, showing 4 columns, orderID, datetimeCreated and datetimeFailed]

Desired Results:

I need to find the last 3 days where orders were done for that customer, this could be 3 orders a day for the last 3 days, or 1 order a week for the last 3 weeks, and I'm looking to see if there is a failure on each of those days (Being is there a row in the order.datafailure table for each day of the last 3 days)

[image: Image showing a filter on customer]

In this image I have filtered on the customer,
the query needs to be able to look and see that there has been a failure on 2020-03-12, then check the next day, 2019-12-13, also failure and 2015-07-13, no failure

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: A `TOP` without an `ORDER BY` will simply return 3 arbitrary rows and those rows could easily be different *every* time you run the query.